# SignalR and Java (j2me)

Tags: java, java-me, signalr

Please tell me whether really make the app .jar(j2me) for mobile devices, which would be exchanged with the data ІshptfdK server? search on this site and Google has not led to any results. If so, what libraries may have a ready to use or what to read on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

According your Title . SignalR in Android (java) . You can try Use SignalA

This is GitHub Project you can clone and change it

[SignalA](https://github.com/erizet/SignalA)